# CSS width not fitting content and wraps for longer text

Tags: css, sass, primeng

I am using primeng tooltip to display tooltip. I want the text to fit the content without wrapping and dont want to set fixed width.

following style not working for me.

```
        <a
            *ngIf="option.url"
            id="main-nav-{{ option.id }}"
            class="main-option"
            (click)="customNavigate(option)"
            [pTooltip]="option.label"
        >
            <i class="fas fa-fw" [class]="option.icon"></i>
            <span>{{ option.label }}</span>
        </a>

.p-tooltip .p-tooltip-text {
    background: $dark;
    color: $light;
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    padding: 0.45rem 0.9rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 999999997;
    max-width: 14rem;
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

In the below first image, how to get 'Event Reporting' in single line?
[image]

[image]

with white-space: nowrap
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: And what html does that css apply to?

Comment: @mahan Thanks. i have edited with result of white-space: nowrap. the rightside is not fitting.

Comment: Could you add your HTML code too?

Comment: yes added the html

Comment: Adding,  white-space: nowrap; max-width: fit-content; width: 100em; worked for me. Not sure it is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Adding following to the above style worked for me:

```
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: fit-content;
width: 100em;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
white-space: nowrap;
width: fit-content;
```